# Passing parameters in link jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I'm currently using the following code to pass parameters from my main page to a popup in jquery mobile:

```
<a onclick= DisplayEditIdPopUP('" . $row ['IdentificationTypeID'] ."','".$custid."','". $num."','".$row ['CustomerIdentificationId']."')>Edit</a>
```

however, Ive setup a zoom plugin which seems to break my on click. Is there a way to pass parameters through a regular anchor tag, without using the on click event? As calling the popup using the following code works, but obviously doesn't pass any parameters at the moment?

```
<a href='#addCustId' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop' class='ui-btn ui-btn-c' >New</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: you've not passed the onclick event on second.....

Comment: I know, that is my question, is there a way to pass parameters to the popup without using the on click event. I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several solutions exist:

**Solution 1:**

You can pass values with changePage:

```
$.mobile.changePage('page2.html', { dataUrl : "page2.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : true, changeHash : true });
```

And read them like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index", function (event, data) {
    var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
    parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
    alert(parameter);
});
```

#### Example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index",function () {
            $(document).on('click', "#changePage",function () {     
                $.mobile.changePage('second.html', { dataUrl : "second.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : false, changeHash : true });
            }); 
        }); 

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#second",function () {
            var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
            parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
            alert(parameter);
        });         
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
          <a data-role="button" id="changePage">Test</a>
        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

**second.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">

        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

**Solution 2:**

Or you can create a persistent javascript object for a storage purpose. As long ajax is used for page loading (and page is not reloaded in any way) that object will stay active.

```
var storeObject = {
    firstname : '',
    lastname : ''
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/9KKbx/

**Solution 3:**

You can also access data from the previous page like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index',function (e, data) {
    alert(data.prevPage.attr('id'));
});
```

**prevPage** object holds a complete previous page.

**Solution 4:**

As a last solution we have a nifty HTML implementation of localStorage. It only works with HTML5 browsers (including Android and iOS browsers) but all stored data is persistent through page refresh.

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
    localStorage.firstname="Dragan";
    localStorage.lastname="Gaic";            
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/J9NTr/

Find more about them **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/passing-data-between-jquery-mobile-pages/)**.